# COMO QUITAR PALABRAS EN EL RESULTADO DE UNA CONSULTA

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

tengo este resultado de una consulta que hice, pero quisiera poder quitar de todos la siguiente frase .... **Servicios TI > Telecomunicaciones >**  y que me quede solo el resto de la oracion. 
Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT Categoria_ITIL, count(*) AS #Tickets
FROM tickets_noviembre 
where Categoria_ITIL LIKE 'Servicios TI > Telecomunicaciones%' 
GROUP BY Categoria_ITIL
ORDER BY #Tickets DESC
```

Adjunto imagen de resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la función `REPLACE()`

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(Categoria_ITIL,'Servicios TI > Telecomunicaciones >','') as Categoria_ITIL, 
    count(*) AS #Tickets
    FROM tickets_noviembre 
    where Categoria_ITIL LIKE 'Servicios TI > Telecomunicaciones%' 
    GROUP BY Categoria_ITIL
    ORDER BY #Tickets DESC
```

Comment: Seria conveniente agregar la funcion LTRIM para eliminar el espacio `REPLACE(LTRIM(Categoria_ITIL,'Servicios TI > Telecomunicaciones >','')) as Categoria_ITIL`